# Android OpenGL ES Overlaying backgrounds

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am currently trying to have a particle fountain spurt out random particles overlaying ontop of a volcano background (textured quad).

I have the volcano backgound and the particles draw statement inside the onDrawFrame

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{

    // Set the clear colour to red and clear the screen
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Enable the vertex array client state
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    background.draw(gl);
    // Draw then update the position of all particles


    for (VolcanoParticle p : particleArray)
    {
        p.draw(gl);
        p.update();
    }

    //background.draw(gl);
    // Disable the vertex array client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

}
```

The "background.draw(gl);" is meant do use the class's in VolcanoBackground.java while the p.draw(gl); is meant to use the VolcanoParticle.java. But for some reason the VolcanoParticle.draw is also affecting the background.draw causing the background to also have the same movements and colorchanges / gravity / movement as the particles.

any ideas on how to fix?

Also with the background.draw it makes the particles very hard to see as if there is a black shroud over the top of them, is there a way to remove this alpha layer or whatever it is or force the background to be behind the particles?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to reset your model-view matrices between drawing each object by calling glLoadIdentity() on them.

Regarding the dimming problem, try disabling lighting.  If that is the problem, then you probably need to move the light closer to the model.